# css selector code to scrape/parse data from tricky website

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, web-scraping, css-selectors

Im having difficulty developing an adequate "CSS selector" code to scrape/parse the odds for the following HTML. I am relatively new to node.js. but ive successfully scraped similar websites in the past. Unfortunately this website is a little more tricky(for me anyway!). I can tell the problem must be the CSS selector code im using. could you please show me how to write a code that allows me to scrape the odds 11/2 from..

```
<div class="market"..............>
   <header class=..........>
   <div class="market-content">
      <div class ="selection">
          <div class="selection name" data-  bind="html:selection.getTitle()"> Aston Villa </div>
          <selection-button params="....>
             <div>
               <div class="odds-button"..........>
                 <span class="price">
                   <span class="odds-convert"......> 11/2 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with just that snippet of HTML, but for that (using jQuery):

```
$('.odds-button > . price > .odds-convert').text();
```

Of course it could be that selector matches somewhere else too, then you'd have to make it more specific by including a longer path. However, making it too specific from the get go makes it too brittle if the structure of the HTML changes.

Comment: the code still doesn't work for some reason. heres the link to the webpage. (im trying to scrape the win odds for Aston Villa)....https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-gb/betting/football/english/premier-league/aston-villa-v-tottenham/221731681/

Comment: All you need is to scrape https://sports.ladbrokes.com/en-gb/events/type/football/english/premier-league - If you want to scrape the page like you tried, you need to wait till it is fully loaded. It is an AJAX drive site that builds the DOM incrementally.

Comment: AJAX, DOM? ...sorry you lost me. im no programmer mate. would it be possible for you to provide an exemplar code showing what you mean

Comment: I fear then I can't really explain those concepts to you. What it boils down is the page is not complete at the moment you try to use the jQuery selector I gave you. What you could try is to delay that by 20s or so: `setTimeout(
  function(){/*Your Code here*/}, 20000);`, then it should work

Comment: yh it still doesnt work. thanks for the help though. im going to have bite the bullet and do a little more research.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you're scraping the content in Node.js, which libraries or techniques you're using, but this is how I'd do it client-side:

```
var oddsElement = document.querySelector([
        ".market",
        ".market-content",
        ".selection",
        // obviously, change below to match your data attribute
        ".selection.name[data-SOME_KEY=\"SOME_VALUE\"]",
        ".odds-button",
        "span.price",
        "span.odds-convert"
    ].join(" "));

if (typeof oddsElement === "object") {
    var odds = (oddsElement.textContent || oddsElement.innerText);
    // or could use "let" keyword in strict-mode Node.js for block-scope
} else { // no match
    console.warn("Odds cannot be found.");
}
```

Comment: thanks.. Any ideas on how to do it using cheerio and request.this seems more complex than i was expecting...

Comment: I've not used `cheerio` before, but, from looking at the docs, it seems like a simple server-side implementation of jQuery's selector methods. So when you get the html body string back from `request`, do this `var $ = cheerio.load(BODY_STRING);`, and then do something similar to Johannes' answer (or the same as mine, just substituting the `$` function for `document.querySelector`, and using the `text` function rather than the `textContent` or `innerText` attributes) to get the odds text.